# SQL Server 2008 R2 Subquery grouping, summing and count

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have a table in the database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.evals (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [agent_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [matrix_1] [int],
    [matrix_2] [int],
    [matrix_2] [int])
```

Each one of the matrix_(x) columns has a default value of 0. When agents are being evaluated by managers it is not required that an entry be made for each matrix. Agents can be evaluated on a daily basis. If a matrix is entered it will have a value between 1 and 5. If not then 0. I need to create a report that sums and averages each matrix for each agent. I need to not count the 0 values when calculating the average so I need to somehow get the count where matrix value <> 0 for each one of these. The report is not for one agent at a time but for all agents in one report. I have tried a general group by agent_id with subqueries to get the matrix count having matrix <> 0 and it does not work. What I want to end up with is something like:

```
select agent_id, sum(matrix_1) / (count(matrix_1) where matrix_1 <> 0), 
          sum(matrix_2) / (count(matrix_2) where matrix_2 <> 0),
          sum(matrix_3) / (count(matrix_3) where matrix_3 <> 0)
group by agent_id
```

That is just pseudo code illustrate the desired result. I have tried using a subquery for each column using a grouping in the subquery but that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question Jim! This should do it. If you want a better average, cast your values as float for the `Avg` aggregation:

```
select
    agent_id,
    sum(matrix_1) Matrix1Sum,
    avg(case when matrix_1 > 0 then cast(matrix_1 as float) end) Matrix1Average,
    sum(matrix_2) Matrix2Sum,
    avg(case when matrix_2 > 0 then cast(matrix_2 as float) end) Matrix2Average,
    sum(matrix_3) Matrix3Sum,
    avg(case when matrix_3 > 0 then cast(matrix_3 as float) end) Matrix3Average
from evals
group by
    agent_id
```

Comment: @ Ron Smith - this is exactly what I needed - works perfect for what my requirements are - thank you.